# Applying where condition on Casted number coulmn in ORACLE from a inner query result

Tags: oracle

For Sample purpose lets create a table with below schema and fill some sample values

```
CREATE TABLE games(ID INT ,Name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO games(ID,Name) VALUES (2008,'Beijing');
INSERT INTO games(ID,Name) VALUES (2012,'London');
INSERT INTO games(ID,Name) VALUES (2012,12);
INSERT INTO games(ID,Name) VALUES (2012,654);
```

Output:

```
ID      NAME
2008    Beijing
2012    London
2012    12
2012    654
```

In the above table we have both number and string data in the name column lets write a query that uses the REGX to filter only the numerical rows

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(Name)as Trimmed FROM games where REGEXP_LIKE(Name, '(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)', '')
```

Output:

```
TRIMMED
12
654
```

Now here is the problem if write a where clause of getting values greater than 12 from the above result it throws **invalid number**.

```
Select * from (SELECT TO_NUMBER(Name)as Trimmed FROM games where REGEXP_LIKE(Name, '(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)', '')) T1 where T1.Trimmed >12 ;
```

I found this is how the oracle query planning works but is there any other way i can achieve this

Comment: This is tagged MySQL and Oracle - which is it as they are two different RDBMSes?

Comment: Syntax suggest Oracle so please remove tag for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Select * from 
  (SELECT Name as Trimmed 
    FROM games where REGEXP_LIKE(Name, '(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)', '')) T1 
where to_number(T1.Trimmed) >12 ;
```

Unfortunately you need a subquery. It can't be done with one where.

Comment: You use `TO_NUMBER()` in the inner query - it is not necessary to use it again in the outer query as that is implicitly doing `WHERE TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( T1.Trimmed ) ) > 12`.

Comment: @MT0 You're right. I've just copied OP's query and haven't noticed that.

Comment: Of course it can be done with one `where`. *I don't know how to do it in a certain way* doesn't always mean *it can't be done in that way.*

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single query:

```
with
     inputs as (
       select 2008 as id, 'Beijing' as name from dual union all
       select 2012      , 'London'          from dual union all
       select 2012      , '12'              from dual union all
       select 2012      , '654'             from dual
     )
select id, name
from   inputs
where  translate(name, 'a0123456789', 'a') is null
  and  to_number(regexp_replace(name, '[^[:digit:]]', '')) > 12
;


        ID NAME
---------- -------
      2012 654

1 row selected.
```

`regexp_replace` removes all the characters except digits, so the test can be done regardless of what the name is. If there are no digits in the name, the result is NULL, which can be converted to number (it is still null).

The `translate` solution for testing for "all-digits" is more efficient than using `regexp_like`. The odd-looking `'a'` in `translate` is needed due to an oddity in the `translate` function itself (see the documentation). This test is not needed if all the names are either "all letters" or "all digits" (if "all letters", the second test with regexp_replace would suffice); but the first test is needed if names like "Sydney 2000" are possible in the `name` column.